# Intellij JUnit5 not working

Tags: java, intellij-idea

So, I have a piece of Java code that I want to test using JUnit 5 in IntelliJ. It is just a simple Client class:

```
public class Client {
    private Integer id;
    private String nam;

    public Client(Integer id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
    return this.name;
    }
}
```

So, I have IntelliJ generate my JUnit5 tests for this class. Here they are:

```
package Domain;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class ClientTest {

    private Client client;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        client = new Client(1, "Emil");
    }

    @AfterEach
    void tearDown() {
        client = null;
    }

    @Test
    void getName() {
        assertEquals("Emil", client.getName());
    }
}
```

Everything is good so far, IntelliJ doesn't highlight any errors. But when I run the tests, this is the output in the console:

```
:cleanTest UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources NO-SOURCE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
/home/emil/Documents/sdi/movierental-nogit/java/src/test/java/Domain/ClientTest.java:3: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
import org.junit.jupiter.api.AfterEach;
                            ^
/home/emil/Documents/sdi/movierental-nogit/java/src/test/java/Domain/ClientTest.java:4: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
                            ^
/home/emil/Documents/sdi/movierental-nogit/java/src/test/java/Domain/ClientTest.java:5: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
                            ^
/home/emil/Documents/sdi/movierental-nogit/java/src/test/java/Domain/ClientTest.java:7: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
                                   ^
/home/emil/Documents/sdi/movierental-nogit/java/src/test/java/TestDomain.java:3: error: package org.junit.jupiter.api does not exist
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
                            ^
/home/emil/Documents/sdi/movierental-nogit/java/src/test/java/Domain/ClientTest.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
    @BeforeEach
     ^
  symbol:   class BeforeEach
  location: class ClientTest
/home/emil/Documents/sdi/movierental-nogit/java/src/test/java/Domain/ClientTest.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    @AfterEach
     ^
  symbol:   class AfterEach
  location: class ClientTest
/home/emil/Documents/sdi/movierental-nogit/java/src/test/java/Domain/ClientTest.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
    @Test
     ^
  symbol:   class Test
  location: class ClientTest
/home/emil/Documents/sdi/movierental-nogit/java/src/test/java/Domain/ClientTest.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        assertEquals("Emil", client.getName());
        ^
  symbol:   method assertEquals(String,String)
  location: class ClientTest
/home/emil/Documents/sdi/movierental-nogit/java/src/test/java/TestDomain.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        Assertions.assertEquals(client.getName(), "Emi");
        ^
  symbol:   variable Assertions
  location: class TestDomain
10 errors
:compileTestJava FAILED
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileTestJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
BUILD FAILED in 0s
3 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 2 up-to-date
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
15:42:15: Tasks execution finished ':cleanTest :test --tests Domain.ClientTest'.
```

This is a gradle project, by the way. I tried everything I found online, all kinds of gradle.build configurations but nothing worked. I find it strange that IntelliJ doesn't highlight any errors, like missing packages or something, yet the errors appear in the console. Does anyone knows what the problem may be?

Comment: Have you tried to rebuild the project?

Comment: Did you add the JUnit 5 dependency to your build.gradle? IntelliJ IDEA will not do it for you automatically.

Comment: Ok, now it works. I found a JUnit sample project and I copied the content of build.gradle into my project, then I rebuilt the project.